# When and how super constructor is called in java

Tags: java

I was trying to understand execution order of constructors using `this()` and `super()` in chained constructors. I tried below code:

```
public class ConstructorChaining{

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new CCC();
    }
} 

class CCA
{
    public CCA() {
        this("");
        System.out.println("Inside A()");
    }

    public CCA(String a) {
        System.out.println("Inside A(String)");
    }
}

class CCB extends CCA 
{
    public CCB() {
        this("");
        System.out.println("Inside B()");
    }

    public CCB(String a) {
        //this(2);
        System.out.println("Inside B(String)");
    }

    public CCB(int a) {
        System.out.println("Inside B(int)");
    }
}

class CCC extends CCB 
{
    public CCC() {
        this("");
        System.out.println("Inside C()");
    }

    public CCC(String a) {
        this(5);
        System.out.println("Inside C(String)");
    }

    public CCC(int a) {
        System.out.println("Inside C(int)");
    }
}
```

This prints following:

```
Inside A(String)
Inside A()
Inside B(String)
Inside B()
Inside C(int)
Inside C(String)
Inside C()
```

So I feel:

If no constructor overload of a class explicitly call `super()`, then all its chained constructor overloads will be executed followed by implicit call to `super()`, which in turn follows same pattern.

In other words, implicit call to parent's default constructor is made in the end after all chained constructor overloads of child class is executed. Diagramatically,

```
CO1() --this()--> CO2() --this()--> ... --this()--> COn              Constructor Overloads (CO) of Class Cn 
                                                     |
                                             Implicit super() call
                                                     |
                                                     v
COn() <--this()-- ... <--this()-- CO2() <--this()-- CO1              Constructor Overloads (CO) of Class Cn-1 which Cn's parent
 |
Implicit super() call
 |
 v
 :
 |
Implicit super() call
 |
 v    
CO1() --this()--> CO2() --this()--> ... --this()--> COn              Constructor Overloads (CO) of Class C1 which is C2's parent
```

If I am correct with this observation, then my doubts is who takes decision when to implicitly call `super()` in the end after all chained constructors of current class are executed? Also, how this decision/behavior is implemented in the jdk / jre? Does the compiler generates bytecode with last call to `super()` or runtime dynamically decides to call `super()`?

Comment: hope this link helps http://etutorials.org/cert/java+certification/Chapter+6.+Object-oriented+Programming/6.3+Chaining+Constructors+Using+this+and+super/

Comment: See [§8.8.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7) and [§12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5) of the _Java Language Specification_.

Answer (score 1):

> If no constructor overload of a class explicitly call super(), then all its chained constructor overloads will be executed followed by implicit call to super(), which in turn follows same pattern.

Incorrect.

If a constructor doesn't start with `this(...)` or `super(...)` then compiler inserts an implicit no-arg `super()`. That is in no way dependent on overloading.

That's it. It's really just that simple. There is no overall logic needed to eventually call a super constructor.

Which is exactly what your diagram shows too. It is constructor `COn` that calls `super()`, because the compiler added it. If all constructors of a call has a `this(...)` or `super(...)`, then the no-arg `super()` is never called.

Comment: ohh my bad!! So, its just that if a constructor does not contain any of `this()` and `super()` calls, compiler implicitly adds `super()` and this constructor eventually becomes `COn` in my diagram. I was unnecessarily thinking of how jdk/jre might be determining which constructor eventually calls `super()`. Also I feel not all constructors can have `this()`.

Comment: *"feel not all constructors can have `this()`"* True, at least one constructor needs to not have `this(...)`, otherwise you have a never-ending call loop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! JVM does a lot of things like this! You may wonder why JVM does this? Is it really necessary? Well, to find out why , consider the following code :

```
class A{
    int a;
    A(int value){ 
        a = value
    }
}

class B extends A{
    int b;
    B(int value){
        b = value;
    }
}
```

If you compile this code, you will get a compile error saying: "There is no default constructor available in A"
That is because JVM doesn't know what value to give to `a`. You may say that the default value of `int` is 0 but what if `A` has an object field and it must be initialized in the constructor before using? So, JVM forces you to call the supper class's constructor in the first line or it calls the default constructor implicitly (and throws an error if there is no default one).